# Evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt{(1-\cos(1/n))\sqrt{(1-\cos(1/n))\dots}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate the limit:$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sqrt{(1-\cos(1/n))\sqrt{(1-\cos(1/n))\dots}}}$$

**My attempt:**

let $l$ be equal to that limit so i can write $$l=\lim_{n\to \infty}{(1-cos(1/n))^{1/2+1/2^2+1/2^3.....\infty}}$$
As i know $$1/2+1/2^2+1/2^3....\infty=1$$
therefore i can write $$l=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\cos(1/n))^1$$
as $n\to \infty, 1/n \to 0$

so $$l=(1-1)=0$$ i don't know why but this is wrong, the correct answer is $1/2$. Can anyone say why i am wrong and show the correct procedure!

Comment: How do you know that the correct answer is $1/2$?

Comment: this question was in my test and on the solution key answer is $1/2$ i lost 5 marks :(

Comment: I assume the number of factors *is* infinite, and does not itself depend on $n$? Be careful about these notations with $\dots$, they hide a lot of useful information and are ambiguous...

Comment: If you have gotten the question correct, your answer is correct. Teachers get wrong answers sometimes, but quite often, the student has misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see, you are just asked to find out
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-\cos(1/n))^1=\lim_{n\to \infty} 1-\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos(1/n)=1-\cos(0)=0.
$$

Comment: so it means i am correct?

Comment: The answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

If 
$$\Phi_n={\sqrt{(1-\cos(1/n))\sqrt{(1-\cos(1/n))\dots}}}$$
defines anything we have:

$$\Phi_n={\sqrt{(1-\cos(1/n))\Phi_n}}$$

Squaring and simplifying gives:

$$\Phi_n=1-\cos(1/n)$$
Hence:$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\Phi_n=0$$

So why do you think the limit is $1/2$?

Comment: 1/2 was given in solution book, that's why i thought i am doing some mistake which i am unable to find